# does devicePixelRatio is really useful

Tags: iphone, html, ios, css, retina-display

I just wonder if the devicePixelRatio related to the web-kit based browsers and Apple's device is really useful, Or it's just apple's private asset. You know, the web-kit engine is also belongs to apple inc. I think this kind of stuff was only meaningful for Apple's  Retina screen, and i always think that the deference between the screen's resolution and OS's resolution should be handled properly by the OS, it's not our task.
If there are lots values of devicePixelRatio range from 0 to 1000000, how many pictures should i prepared for those screens.

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2012/07/more_about_devi.html - have a quick read of that, it might help you.

Comment: i dont undrestand your question,explain better your question please

Comment: "I’m not a big fan of serving special retina images because it makes the web too heavy — especially over a mobile connection. Nonetheless people will do it.

If you use this sort of detection, please remember to build in a case for when devicePixelRatio is neither 1 nor 2 but, for instance, 1.5 or 2.25. " ----   quoted from the web page boz provided. Thanks, this help me get out of this.

Answer (score 1):

Web browsing is the most popular activity for mobile device users and webpages themselves are served in a variety of shapes and sizes.

Apple and the various companies that followed them into the mobile hardware arena needed to make the web browsing experience as easy as possible in order to maximize the amount time spent using and relying on their devices. They needed to avoid having the user pinch and zoom and pan around a page in order to read content, so they exposed an API to web developers known as "meta viewport" which allowed them to serve with little extra effort a small screen adapted versions of their website.

Later they realized that scaling in such a manner made images look like absolute crap when scaled up in a higher dpi device like apple retina AND android devices like the galaxy sIII and nexus devices. So they made a variable devicePixelRatio and a corresponding CSS Media Query to enable web developers to detect that a given device needs higher resolution images in order for a website to look good after being scaled. No one expects website owners/developers to waste 2x the bandwidth serving bitmaps with subpixel data to EVERYONE just because 0.2% of their users happen to be using a device with 2x the usual amount of pixels for a given physical size. In order for a high dpi device to be successful they needed to make the web look good on it and the only way for the web to look good on it is to make it easy and worthwhile enough for a website owner/developer to opt into making their website look good on it.

its up to the website developer to weigh the cost and benefit of taking the extra time to selectively serve images so that a website will not look bad on high pixel density devices. If the web ever comes to a point where most websites are doing this, the consumer will be under the impression that YOUR website is of low quality, not due to some shortcomings in the hardware they are using.

and just to clarify:

apple only uses 1 and 2 for their devicePixelRatio.

google promotes use of 1, 1.5, and 2 (although they cannot always enforce this).

microsoft uses 96dpi (1) 144dpi (1.5) 192dpi (2) in their screen.deviceXDPI value

most people just serve one 2x resolution version of their assets to all devices above some sort of threshold like 1.3 and 1x versions to devices below that. For those web developers who understand what exactly all these device values mean and how to use "CSS Media Queries" or their respective javascript values, it is extremely easy and not as frustrating as I suspect you are imagining it to be.